# Why didn't the EASA enforce the 2 man cockpit rule BEFORE the Gemanwings accident?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation, cockpit

International numbers state that planes downed by pilot or co-pilot due to suicide are a rare but still possible occurrence.

In the United States such a safety procedure is standard (as of 9/11 - if I remember correctly). Why didn't the EASA think of that earlier?

Comment: Note.  On 9/11, there were already 2 crew in the cockpit when they were taken over.

Comment: Oh wow thanks, I didn't know that. Do you have a document or an official statement that proves that?

Comment: Because of 9/11, the rule that cockpit door _must be locked_ was introduced. And the two men rule went with that to handle situation when one of them is _incapacitated_ (which does happen occasionally) so there is still somebody to open the door. It was relaxed when the emergency code that opens the door from outside unless rejected in some time limit was introduced. IIRC it was relaxed _everywhere_, provided the emergency entry code is available.

Comment: @Jan Hudec So 2 men cockpit rule in the US did go hand in hand with 9/11? Is that correct?

Comment: @Elena: Yes, but indirectly. It was only instantiated because the first door locks didn't have the emergency code.

Comment: I didn't mean that the rule was in place, just that on all 4 aircraft., both crew were in the cockpit.  I would guess that was part of the plan - don't attack if one of the cockpit crew is not in the cockpit.  The point being that the 2 man rule would have had no affect on the outcome. Jan Hudec has correctly identified why the rule exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graveyard evolution; new advances are only pushed through when the existing situation is provably not safe.

Aviation history is rife with examples of safety measure being taken after an incident of accident that could have been prevented by that measure.

Comment: Thats what I thought. In their last update on cockpit rules they stated: "EASA publishes today a temporary recommendation for airlines to ensure that at least two crew, including at least one qualified pilot, are in the flight crew compartment at all times of the flight." Why the hell do they only recommend and not require, and why only temporary? They are a regulatory and executive agency - they should be much more stricter with that!!!!

Comment: @Elena Because hasty rule patching causes more harm than good (just ask your local legislative body). Many times there are unforeseen consequences to the rules.

Comment: @Elena Because the EASA possibly does not come to the same conclusion the FAA or other CAAs came to and therefore only issued a temporary recommendation. Many, me included, will argue that the two-man cockpit rule is only changing things for the sake of change and purely cosmetic to show the public that actions are being taken (even though they are ineffective).

Comment: @Sentry Raven so what kind of regulation can be enforced in order to prevent future plane accidents due to intervention by pilot or co-pilot?

Comment: @Elena To be brutally honest, none! There is no way to exclude 100% of all possible scenarios. You can work to minimize or eliminate the probability of some of the possible scenarios, but you will never create a 100% working solution for everything. Look at it this way: The door lock was introduced to keep intruders out of the cockpit. The copilot in GWI18G used that against the pilot. What would be the logical consequence? Remove the door lock! What does that open up again? Possible threat from external intruders! Too many possible threat to consider, so you focus on the most probable ones..

Comment: @SentryRaven makes sense, there are just too many scenarios to consider. So basically you are saying that the 2 man cockpit rule is nonsense anyway. Its just been enforced to calm down the public but practically it won't ensure safety at all (in case of pilot/copilot suicide)?

Comment: @Elena That is my personal opinion, yes. Does it help raise the psychological threshold for pilot or copilot to deliberately crash the aircraft? Yes. Can the copilot/pilot overpower the other pilot/copilot? Yes. Can the copilot/pilot overpower an FA? Yes. Does it also open another can of worms by allowing non-trained personnel into the cockpit? Yes. To me, this is a zero sum game with this change, to show the public that something is being done. I kindly invite you to the [Aviation.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) to continue the discussion.

Comment: @SentryRaven thanks, will happily join!

Comment: One side effect of such a rule is that it lowers the bar for the position someone would have to obtain to take over the aircraft -- instead of needing to become a pilot to gain access to the cockpit during flight, one need "only" become a flight attendant to be in a position where they can gain access to the cockpit with only a single pilot present who could be incapacitated.  (I realize one can't just walk off the street and become a flight attendant, but it's much easier to become a FA than to become a pilot on a large aircraft)

Answer (score 7):

Because aviation procedures and rules develop from historical occurances.

In some cases, the actual occurance and the resulting change in procedures do not have anything in common or are not related, e.g. some will argue that the two-man rule would not have prevented 9/11. It is also being discussed that the two man rule would only have had a psychological effect to deter the pilot/copilot from deliberately crashing the plane (as in the Germanwings crash), some will argue that a pilot or co-pilot intent to deliberately crash the airplane will not be deterred by a flight attendant in the cockpit, who due to lack of flight education would not be able to counter the pilot's/copilot's input in the FMC/AP.

The cockpit door measures to deny unauthorized access to the cockpit were implemented because the threat was assumed to come from outside the cockpit. You cannot implement measures that will work against everything and every threat, internal or external. Hence why EASA (and this is only speculative, because we can't know for sure) did not implement a two-man rule and currently has not implemented one, the two-man rule is a airline SOP issue at the moment.